# Eclipse indent multi line variable assignments and class definitions

Tags: java, eclipse, autoformatting

I just recently upgraded to Eclipse Oxygen and now the auto-formatting is making me crazy. I can not figure out how to get my custom formatter working the way I want it to be.

This is the code I have

```
public class SomeClass 
    extends SomeOtherClass
    implements SomeInterface
{

    private final int someVariableWithALongName
        = theValueReturnedFromAMethodWithAVeryLongName();

}
```

I like this style of indentation and I want to keep it. Somehow I had an older version of Eclipse configured to not remove this custom indentation by auto formatting. In the new Oxygen the auto formatter does this:

```
public class SomeClass
extends SomeOtherClass
implements SomeInterface
{

    private final int someVariableWithALongName
    = theValueReturnedFromAMethodWithAVeryLongName();

}
```

And I found no way to change it. I would prefer my custom formatting if anyway possible without disabling auto formatting!

Comment: Create a formater profile and configure it. In the "Line Wrapping" tab, ensure that  "never join already wrapped lines" is checked.

Comment: @davidxxx I have that option already set in my custom formatter.

Comment: Maybe the breakline character previously entered is not recognized in this new version of Eclipse. Try to do a new break line char and  apply the auto format. Which result do you get ?

Comment: @davidxxx I still get the same result. Regardless of break line character or whether I use previously written code or newly written code (written in Oxygen).

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new formatter profile (*Window > Preferences: Java > Code Style > Formatter*) based on the built-in Eclipse profile, you must change at least the following to get a formatting as specified by your example (in your current profile, it seems only the first setting is missing):

- ***Line Wrapping***

  - Set ***Default indention for wrapped lines*** to ***1***
  - For both *Class Declarations > 'extends'* and *'implements' clause*:

    - Set *Line wrapping policy* to *Wrap first element, others where necessary*
    - Check *Force split, even if line shorter than maximum line width*
  - *Expressions > Assignments*:

    - Set *Line wrapping policy* to *Wrap where necessary*
    - Check *Wrap before operator*
- *Braces*

  - *Class or interface declaration: Next line*

To configure or disable format on save see: *[Automatically format and cleanup code every time you save](http://www.eclipseonetips.com/2009/12/13/automatically-format-and-cleanup-code-every-time-you-save/)* (option: *Format source code*)